# xpath query with predicates

Tags: javascript, xpath

I'm having a problem formating an xpath query. I'm trying to get products that have a serviceTechnology = 'DSL'.

I've tried:

`//offering/productDefinition[definitionID='Product_1' or 
                              definitionID='Product_2' or
                              definitionID='Product_3' or
                              definitionID='Product_4'
                     and serviceTechnologyList[serviceTechnology='DSL']]`

`//offering/productDefinition[definitionID='Product_1' or 
                              definitionID='Product_2' or
                              definitionID='Product_3' or
                              definitionID='Product_4'
                      and serviceTechnologyList='DSL']`

This was based on other questions list here. I keep getting "Predicate Format Error".

```
<offeringList>
    <offering>
        <productDefinition>
            <definitionID>Product_1</definitionID>
            <productLineList>
                <productLine>DSL</productLine>
            </productLineList>
            <serviceTechnologyList>
                <serviceTechnology>DSL</serviceTechnology>
            </serviceTechnologyList>
        </productDefinition>
    </offering>
    <offering>
        <productDefinition>
            <definitionID>Product_2</definitionID>
            <productLineList>
                <productLine>DSL</productLine>
            </productLineList>
            <serviceTechnologyList>
                <serviceTechnology>IPTV</serviceTechnology>
            </serviceTechnologyList>
        </productDefinition>
    </offering>
    <offering>
        <productDefinition>
            <definitionID>Product_3</definitionID>
            <productLineList>
                <productLine>DSL</productLine>
            </productLineList>
            <serviceTechnologyList>
                <serviceTechnology>DSL</serviceTechnology>
            </serviceTechnologyList>
        </productDefinition>
    </offering>
    <offering>
        <productDefinition>
            <definitionID>Product_4</definitionID>
            <productLineList>
                <productLine>DSL</productLine>
            </productLineList>
        </productDefinition>
    </offering>
</offeringList>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Both XPath expressions are syntactically correct. If you are getting an error this means that either you were using different expressions or the XPath engine you are using is buggy/incompliant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just:

```
/offeringList/offering/productDefinition[serviceTechnologyList/serviceTechnology = 'DSL']
```

Or you can do the following if you want to be specific about definitionIDs:

```
//offeringList/offering/productDefinition[serviceTechnologyList/serviceTechnology = 'DSL'][definitionID='Product_1' or definitionID='Product_2' or definitionID='Product_3' or definitionID='Product_4']
```

Comment: There are about 60+ products in total and not all have a serviceTechnology of 'DSL'. I only want the products that have the specific definitionID and have a serviceTechnology of 'DSL'.

Comment: Mark, I used the second suggestion with the specific definition IDs and it seems to work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I see no errors at glance - both work:), maybe you are not escaping something ?

Try your queries here to see that work ok: [xpath tester](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You need parentheses to define the priority of `and` and `or` operators:

```
//offering/productDefinition[(definitionID='Product_1' or definitionID='Product_2' or definitionID='Product_3' or definitionID='Product_4') and serviceTechnologyList[serviceTechnology='DSL']]
```

If you just want `productDefinition` nodes that have `serviceTechnology='DSL'`, you can simplify to something like:

```
//productDefinition[serviceTechnologyList[serviceTechnology='DSL']]
```

Comment: There are about 60+ products in total and not all have a serviceTechnology of 'DSL'. I only want the products that have the specific definitionID and have a serviceTechnology of 'DSL'.

Comment: OK, then the first one should work fine. Are you still experiencing issues?

Answer (score 0):

As @icyrock.com points out, the problem is in boolean operators: `and` has more precedence than `or`.

This expression use another approach for matching against a sequence in XPath 1.0:

```
//offering/productDefinition
             [contains('|Product_1|Product_2|Product_3|Product_4|',
                       concat('|',definitionID,'|')) 
              and serviceTechnologyList/serviceTechnology='DSL']
```

If the list of ID gets too big, you could use:

```
//offering/productDefinition
             [starts-with(definitionID,'Product_')
              and contains('|1|2|3|4|6|8|22|',
                           concat('|',
                                  substring-after(definitionID,
                                                  'Product_'),
                                  '|')) 
              and serviceTechnologyList/serviceTechnology='DSL']
```

Or if there is a range:

```
//offering/productDefinition
             [starts-with(definitionID,'Product_')
              and substring-after(definitionID,'Product_') >= 1
              and 4 >= substring-after(definitionID,'Product_')
              and serviceTechnologyList/serviceTechnology='DSL']
```